# How do I make website images and slideshows look like they are a device screen?

Tags: html, image, css, web

There are lots of website themes that have a slideshow or image frame that is styled to look like it's a device such as a mobile screen or tablet screen or computer monitor.  Please see below:

[image: This is an example image of pictures in a device screen]

I have spent the last 4 hours looking for some code or an open source plugin that would enable me to show images this way. All I have found in 4 hours is yootheme and hostmoog that both charge for the plugin.

How does everyone else get these device style frames around images please?  Do I need graphics software?

This question should help others too.  I've spent ages searching under every conceivable combination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly? I always thought the small-screen representations were screenshots on/within a styled element (the element styled to look like the screen/frame/monitor of the relevant device).

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  If you just need a few images to have an ipad/device border around them for a slideshow or to display them then photoshop or any graphics software(GIMP is free) is your best solution.  Can you link some examples of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. 

David - that's just what I'm saying, I need some code (css3), but there are other ways to do this.

Matt, below are a couple of links: slideshow and a static view.

I looked in clipart because I thought there'd be a phone style frame option as there are others - but no.  I was sure there must be a graphic software approach.  

http://www.yootheme.com/demo/#nano2

http://www.yootheme.com/widgetkit/examples/#

Thanks quinxorin, I stumbled across this way before on some blog but forgot about it.  I'll have a go.

Developer looper - thanks, but not what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create your device "background". Then, divide the images into four pieces:

```
The part of the background that appears above the top of the screen image
The part that appears below the bottom of the screen image
The part that appears to the left of the image between the top and bottom
The part that appears to the right of the image between the top and bottom.
```

Then, create three `<div>`s. Place the top and bottom pieces in `<div>`s 1 and 3, and divide the 2nd  into three smaller `<div>`s. Render the left and right pieces in the left and right sub-`<div>`, and finally, render your slideshow in the center piece.

Comment: Please see my comment at the bottome about CSS3 and Photoshop PSD approaches to this problem - there are a few links to resources.  I'm going to take one of these templates and use quinxorin's approach (thanks) to getting the screen image into my site. By the way I am fine for an iphone image as I have an iphone simulator on my PC, so I just took a screenshot with my site loaded up.  There are similar tools online where you can check what your site looks like in an iphone so you won't need to install the simulator. Thanks for the comments everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your question perfectly, and I may be way off, but I'm going to try to answer it to it from what I think your asking. [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) is what you're looking for. Displaying the page perfectly across all devices.

There is also a tool that I use to see my webpages in different resolutions, [Resize my browser](http://resizemybrowser.com/) that lets me see how my page will look on different size browers, iphones, etc... If your code is correct this is a very useful site.

Hope I somewhat answered this question.

Comment: Found these:

CSS:

iphone_4_rendered_using_html5_and_css3_no_images_needed.html

http://tjrus.com/iphone

http://www.techhive.com/article/247229/iphone_4_rendered_using_html5_and_css3_no_images_needed.html


PSD 

http://brightbrightgreat.com/2013/04/16/free-download-slate-collection-of-stylized-apple-product-psds-retina-ready-fully-scalable-mockups/

http://avant5-stock.deviantart.com/art/iPhone-PSD-215969964

http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/icon-design/create-a-photo-realistic-iphone-in-photoshop/

http://www.bigstockphoto.com/image-37904272/stock-photo-modern-computer-monitor-isolated

Comment: Also, here is a great site that takes a screenshot of your website and shrinks it to drop on top of a monitor image: http://www.shrinktheweb.com/