# Rendering mobile simulated view inside image of mobile phone on desktop browser

Tags: mobile

I am relatively new to SO, and this is my first question so I hope I get the format & question information correct. I am looking for a plugin or tool that can assist me with a specific display issue.

I have a mobile application that is deployed to both Android and iOS devices. I also have a mobile web application that renders very much like the actual mobile application in the mobile device web browser when the user browses certain parts of the server back end cloud service website on their mobile device. So far so good.

However, when the user browses these parts of the cloud service website on a desktop/laptop, they get the web application view - **some of it stretched and not ideally optimised as this is really for viewing on mobile devices**. The client would like that a user, on desktop/laptop browser can see a mobile 'simulated' view of the web application.

It has to happen when the user navigates to the page, not through installing chrome plugins etc

I see the ideal solution being something like an i**mage of a generic mobile for when browsing on desktop, centred on the desktop screen, inside of which the web app view is rendered.** Is there is plugin/tool that someone out there for this, I have done quite a bit of research and can only find information on emulators for testing etc. In a way all I am looking for is an image that dynamically resizes inside of which a view can be rendered, that looks well across many desktop screen sizes/resolutions etc. Rather than go about this myself (it would be a bit of a CSS learning curve for me) it would be great if something like this already existed.

An implementation like the above would free up real estate on the screen for other items like links and form buttons the client wants

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this work for you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16990289/15741905

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

Set the image as background image with `position: relative`.
Put content inside div with `position: absolute`.
And set the div margins with below function.

You need to find topFrameDivider, bottomFrameDivider and sideFrameDivider manually by console.logs on the browser. They are the ratios of the frame to the overall image.

```js
function updateMargins() {
      const innerScreenRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      const phoneFrameRatio = backgroundImage.width / backgroundImage.height;

      const isMaxHeight = innerScreenRatio > phoneFrameRatio;

      console.log('isMaxHeight', isMaxHeight);

      const topFrameDivider = 9.62;
      const bottomFrameDivider = 11;
      const sideFrameDivider = 27.6;

      let top: string, bottom: string, left: string, right: string;

      if (isMaxHeight) {
        const phoneWidth = window.innerHeight * phoneFrameRatio;
        const emptyHorizontalSpace = window.innerWidth - phoneWidth;
        const sideMargin =
          emptyHorizontalSpace / 2 + phoneWidth / sideFrameDivider + 'px';

        top = window.innerHeight / topFrameDivider + 'px';
        bottom = window.innerHeight / bottomFrameDivider + 'px';
        left = sideMargin;
        right = sideMargin;
        console.log('phoneWidth', phoneWidth);

        setMargin({top, bottom, left, right});
      } else {
        const phoneHeight = window.innerWidth / phoneFrameRatio;
        const emptyVerticalSpace = window.innerHeight - phoneHeight;
        const topMargin =
          emptyVerticalSpace / 2 + phoneHeight / topFrameDivider + 'px';
        const bottomMargin =
          emptyVerticalSpace / 2 + phoneHeight / bottomFrameDivider + 'px';

        top = topMargin;
        bottom = bottomMargin;
        left = window.innerWidth / sideFrameDivider + 'px';
        right = window.innerWidth / sideFrameDivider + 'px';

        setMargin({top, bottom, left, right});
      }

    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateMargins);
```